# How to skip or avoid duplicate keys from json when using for_each

Tags: json, terraform

I am trying to generate Terraform resources from a JSON file that has duplicate keys.
Is there any way to avoid the duplicate?

Here is an example JSON

```
{
  "my-ptr-zone": {
    "21-10": {
      "zone"  : "21.10.in-addr.arpa"
    },

    "21-10": {
      "zone"  : "21.10.in-addr.arpa"
    }
  }
}
```

Both the keys are the same here.

And here is the resource

```
resource "aws_route53_zone" "my-ptr-zone" {
  for_each = var.my-ptr-zone
  name     = each.value.zone
}
```

Is there any way to skip the duplicates when looping?

I have tried to avoid generating duplicate values in the JSON file from the source, but that is another challenge.

Comment: Duplicates of what? Sadly your question lacks details and is unclear. What errors do you get with the current code?

Comment: Sorry, i am totally new to this. let me modify my question to make it more clear. thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Terraform's `jsondecode` function reacts to duplicate property names in a single object by discarding all but the last definition of a particular name.

In the example shown in your question, `jsondecode` of the JSON document shown would produce the following Terraform value:

```
{
  "my-ptr-zone" = {
    "21-10" = {
      "zone" = "21.10.in-addr.arpa"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to generate only one resource per unique key in a map, ask Terraform to generate a *set* of the keys, then loop over those.

Consider the following example using the [hashicorp/random](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/random/latest/docs) provider.

```
locals {
  my-ptr-zone = {
    "21-10" = {
      zone = "21.10.in-addr.arpa"
    }
    "21-10" = {
      zone = "21.10.in-addr.arpa"
    }
  }
}

resource "random_id" "example" {
  for_each = toset(keys(local.my-ptr-zone))
  byte_length = 8
}
```

Planning that with `terraform plan`, you'll see that terraform only wants to generate one resource.

```
# random_id.example["21-10"] will be created
+ resource "random_id" "example" {
  + b64_std     = (known after apply)
  + b64_url     = (known after apply)
  + byte_length = 8
  + dec         = (known after apply)
  + hex         = (known after apply)
  + id          = (known after apply)
}

Plan: 1 to add, 0 to change, 0 to destroy.
```

Change one of the keys to something different, and terraform will want to create two resources.

```
# random_id.example["21-10"] will be created
...

# random_id.example["21-11"] will be created
...

Plan: 2 to add, 0 to change, 0 to destroy.
```

If you instead are interested in some other uniqueness (e.g. only the unique values of `zone`), the same approach could be applied ... generate a *set* of the things you want to be unique, then iterate over that set.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to approach this would be to run a [`merge`](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/merge) on the map twice.

JSON File:

```json
{
  "my-ptr-zone": {
    "21-10": {
      "zone"  : "21.10.in-addr.arpa"
    },

    "21-10": {
      "zone"  : "21.10.in-addr.arpa"
    }
  }
}
```

TF Code:

```
locals {
  data  = jsondecode(file("data.json"))
  zones = merge(local.data.my-ptr-zone, local.data.my-ptr-zone)
}

output "zones" {
  value = local.zones
}

# This will now be a unique resource
resource "aws_route53_zone" "my-ptr-zone" {
  for_each = local.zones
  name     = each.value.zone
}
```

Output:

```
Outputs:

zones = {
  "21-10" = {
    "zone" = "21.10.in-addr.arpa"
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!
That helped. Solved it with your guide.

Comment: @acuren don't forget to select the answer and up vote if it and your questions.